# Default SP2007 Workflows Upgrade Issues to SP2010

Tags: workflow, upgrade

We recently completed an upgrade (database attach hybrid) from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010. We have come across an issue in which one of our sites used the default approval workflows, but since upgrading, these are no longer available.

Our site consumers had several workflow instances in transit during the upgrade and were able to "complete" the workflows via email but not by using the right-click menu options as the workflows are no longer available.

No workflow option were activated for the site or site collection in 2010. What do we need to activate/configure in order to make these available again?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read around, sharepoint 2007 workflows are migrated and work but do not behave correctly. This happened to me.

To get the 2010 workflows to show up you need to activate the feature from the site collection feature list. Its called 'Workflows' and I saw it at the bottom. When that is done you should see them show up as workflow options in the list box.

To get the 2007 to work correctly you need to turn on the 'SharePoint 2007 Workflows' in the site collections features list.

What we did was just finish out the old workflows and started entirely new with 2010 workflows.